# Are there sources which cite art as being an extension of spiritual practice in Jewish tradition?

Tags: history, rabbis, art

I understand this question may be interpreted as being slightly generalized but I'm asking for sources which cite the religious/spiritual nature of art in Jewish practice.

Obviously, statues of people are considered a problem in certain instances. That being said, I'm speaking to art as a general idea rather than any specific medium.

Are there opinions or statements from the sages and respected Rabbis which cite that art is an extension of Jewish practice/spirituality. That, or art being a way for a Jew to express what they cannot express with words in relation to their love of Hashem?

The closest I know off hand is that skilled individuals had the ability to offer their highest quality creations during the temple offering period, people would be able to offer things outside of animal sacrifices. An example being a baker who brings his most perfect Challah as an offering at the Korban.

While that may be food, it can be argued it is also an extension of one's skill and ability to create art. The idea being you are bringing something you've extended your highest form of skill and excellence to as a show of gratitude.

My question is where does art tie into this and can art be considered a divine expression according to Jewish tradition?

Comment: Can you source the baker bringing a challah as an offering?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm speaking to the idea of the two loaves which were offered as a symbol of the new harvest. The Shtei Halechem. 

These were supposed to have been created with the highest quality of the harvest and you could not bring other sacrifices before these two offerings were made.